# Transferred IOTA from Binance but my balance won't change from 0

Tags: wallet, iota-network, binance

I transferred about 27 IOTA from Binance on the 29th. However, my wallet is not showing any balance and no matter what I try, there is still no balance. I am not sure if my wallet was fully synced or not when I generated my receive address (could this be the problem?).

Are my coins truly gone? Is there no way to get them back? Here is the transaction:
https://thetangle.org/transaction/FUVGTAISPIWXNKMCGHMWCWRT9W9PPMPMHQWAQAPOSXHEJNTTBLFKADCZFLIGHX9QFCTDT9LUWCNEA9999

Comment: Is `WHUBOKCTKHEPBLNDWHRSFGZWVXFNS9IWSBHPMSYCHEVHIJC9LZHXPAPXEUZOMQWDLU9ZPMRCACB9LJBIAOUAYSDJEC` one of your addresses? Go to HISTORY to see your addresses.If it doesn't show up, go to *RECEIVE* and click *ATTACH TO TANGLE* or *GENERATE NEW ADDRESS* several times.

Comment: @Zauz No it does not show up in my history. Someone suggested that maybe I put in the wrong seed but it just seems very unlikely because I copy and paste it every time. If I was not synced when I originally generated the address, could that have been the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "not synced" a light wallet dont have to sync?
Also can you add a screen from your history.